# Can't load image on Imageview from URI

Tags: android, file, imageview, uri

I'm trying to load an Image stored on the application files folder
When i open the Activity I'm getting this error from logcat:

> 1-20 01:30:40.125 14331-14331/mx.eusaga.af W/ImageView: Unable to open
>   content:
>   content://mx.eusaga.af.fileprovider/imagenes/1-db384fa8-f28b-4595-abbf-d45d38fd4036.jpg
>                                                            java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
>                                                                at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
>                                                                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:253)
>                                                                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:199)
>                                                                at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.openFile(FileProvider.java:545)
>                                                                at android.content.ContentProvider.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1322)
>                                                                at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1502)
>                                                                at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1568)
>                                                                at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:391)
>                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1080)
>                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:921)
>                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:646)
>                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:768)
>                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:429)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageURI(AppCompatImageView.java:124)
>                                                                at mx.eusaga.af.Adapter.ImagenAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ImagenAdapter.java:51)
>                                                                at mx.eusaga.af.Adapter.ImagenAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ImagenAdapter.java:30)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
>                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(L

The code Im using to get the image is the following:

```
private Uri obtenerImagen(String archivo) {
    File Directorio = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/imagenes/");
    Directorio.mkdirs();
    File imagen = new File(Directorio,archivo + ".jpg");
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"mx.eusaga.af.fileprovider",imagen);
    return uri;
}
```

This is my fileprovider:

```
<!-- FileProvider -->
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="mx.eusaga.af.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

and these are my file paths:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="imagenes" path="imagenes/"/>
</paths>
```

The folder **imagenes** and the file **1-db384fa8-f28b-4595-abbf-d45d38fd4036.jpg** exist in the correct folder.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String folderpath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/files";
 String imagefolderpath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/files" +  "/images";

 File fileFolder = new File(folderpath);
        // check if file Folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
        if (!fileFolder.exists()) {
            fileFolder.mkdir();
        }

File imageFolder = new File(imagefolderpath);
        // check if image Folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
        if (!imageFolder.exists()) {
            imageFolder.mkdir();
        }

String imageFilePath = imageFolder + "/test.jpg";

File imagePath = new File(imageFilePath);
if (!imageFolder.exists()) {
    Log.d("Log","Image not exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/?
You can load image from a file with way less code.

Comment: I've trying to load it with `Picasso.with(context).load(obtenerImagen(imagen.getImagen())).into(holder.imageView);` but is still not finding the image

Answer (score 0):

Ur error says

```
FileNotFoundException
```

Means the path you are providing is invalid..
Plz check your directory and file path

Comment: And how i can get the path to the files folder of my app??

Answer (score 0):

> you have not added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE premission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

> for permission grant at runtime use following code.

```
    public final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;
    public static final int NO_RESULT = -5;
    public static final String ALERT_TITLE = "Demo";
```

> call method in onCreate()

```
    askMarshmallowPermissions();




>   private void askMarshmallowPermissions() {
>             List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();
>     
>             final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
>     
>             if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
>                 permissionsNeeded.add("Write to storage");
>     
>             if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
>                 if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
>                     // Need Rationale
>                     String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
>                     for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
>                         message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
>                     showMessageOKCancel(message,
>                             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                                 @Override
>                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
>                                     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
>                                             permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
>                                             REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
>                                 }
>                             });
>                     return;
>                 }
>                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
>                         REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
>                 return;
>             }
>             callAfterPermission();
>         }
>     
>       
>       private void callAfterPermission() {
>           // your code after premission granted.
>       }



    private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        showAlertDialogWithFinishActivity(MainActivity.this,
                                "01 - Please grant all required permissions to " +
                                        "continue running the app. Please Restart the App and allow Permissions.",
                                ALERT_TITLE, true, NO_RESULT, null);
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();
    }

  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                // Initial
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

                // Fill with results
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                if (perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    callAfterPermission();
                } else {

                    showAlertDialogWithFinishActivity(MainActivity.this,
                            "02 - Please grant all required permissions to " +
                                    "continue running the app. Please restart the app and allow permissions.",
                            ALERT_TITLE, true, NO_RESULT, null);
                }
            }
            break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Currently I’m using an emulator and the pictures are in the directory /data/data/mx.eusaga.af/files/images, aren’t this directory internal??

Comment: I have added one more answer, please check