# Trying to create folder in internal storage but code working only in oppo handset not in other brand handsets

Tags: android

Trying to create folder in internal storage but code working only in oppo handset not in other brand handsets like samsung,mi etc

```
public void createPDF()
{

    TextView dttt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dttt);
    String da  = dttt.getText().toString();
    final Cursor cursor = db.getDateWise(da);



    Document doc = new Document();


    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CollactionApp"+ "/PDF";

        File dir = new File(path);
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

        int i = 1;
        File file = new File(dir, "Datewise" + da + ".pdf" );
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

        //open the document
        doc.open();
```

}

Comment: are you sure that it depends on the brand, not on Android version?

Comment: Did you check these android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions that in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: `if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();` Change to `if(!dir.exists())
            if (!dir.mkdirs()){Toast(.....); return;}`.

Comment: I have tried in so many phones but it is working only in oppo brand mobile not in other phones. In other phones i m able to make folder in package folder but not in main directary.

Comment: `are you sure that it depends on the brand, not on Android version?` You did not react. Shame on you. It depends on the Android version.

Comment: `able to make folder in package folder but not in main directary` It is unclear what you consider to be 'the main folder'. It is unclear what you consider to be 'the package folder'.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check premissions in Manifest and at run time


String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        createExDirectory("CollactionApp", root_sd);
        String path = root_sd + "/CollactionApp"+ "/PDF.pdf";
        File f = new File(path);
        try {
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        public static String createExDirectory(String folderName, String pathToExternalStorage) {
        String returnPath = "";
        boolean success = false;
        Boolean isSDPresent = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        if (isSDPresent) {
            // SD-card is present
            File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage + "/" + folderName);
            if (appDirectory.exists()) {
                success = true;
            } else {
                success = appDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            if (success) {
                returnPath = appDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
            } else {
            }
        }
        return returnPath;
    }
```

Comment: same problem exist working in oppo but not in samsung

Comment: upload Error log in question

Comment: I tried in emulator too. Also working fine there problem with real device only.

Comment: check it again. log not found

Comment: i tried it so many times. It does not show any exception. but does not create folder too

Comment: i think your permissions are missing, check thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351800/cant-load-image-on-imageview-from-uri

Answer (score 0):

The path you are using points to the external storage. I've had an app before which have been working for long on all devices until recently, so I had to do a refactor on it, so I don't use the getExternalStorageDirectory() anymore.

I now use the `Context`'s `getFilesDir()`, on which I didn't get the same issue again.

You would want your path to be something like below to use internal storage.

```
File internalDir = getContext().getFilesDir();
File myFolder = new File(internalDir, "/CollactionApp"+ "/PDF");
String path = myFolder.getAbsolutePath;
```